# Powershell: how to replace a value within format-table

Tags: powershell

I want to shorten Directory with relative path:

```
$Dir = get-childitem C:\temp -recurse
$List = $Dir | where {$_.extension -eq ".txt"}
$List | format-table name, Directory -replace "C:\temp", ""
```

I get this error:

```
Format-Table : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'replace'.
At line:3 char:38
+ $List | format-table name, Directory -replace "C:\temp", ""
+                                      ~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Format-Table], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NamedParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.FormatTableCommand
```

What's the right syntax ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a [calculated property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object). Example:

```
$List | Format-Table name,
  @{Name = "Directory"; $Expression = {$_.FullName -replace "C:\\temp", ""}}
```

A calculated property is simply a hashtable that dictates the content of the property. Calculated properties are available with formatting cmdlets that select properties and output a new custom object (e.g, `Select-Object`, `Format-List`, etc.).

(As an aside: The `-replace` operator uses a regular expression, so you would need to write `C:\\temp` instead of just `C:\temp`.)

If your goal is to output file system item directory names: `Directory` is not a property of all file system objects. Is this what you mean?

```
Get-ChildItem C:\Temp\*.txt -Recurse | Format-Table Name,
  @{Name = "Directory"; Expression = {$_.FullName -replace 'C:\\temp', ''}}
```

Note how this command takes advantage of the pipeline (no need for the intermediate `$List` or `$Dir` variables).

Comment: I believe you need a double slash for the `-replace` regex to work.

Comment: @Bill_Stewart I get this error: A null key is not allowed in a hash literal.

Comment: @HAL9256 I added double slash but there seems there's already an error see my comment above

Comment: I think it's not "Name" but "Label" see answer below

Comment: Ah @Bill_Stewart You are right, I didn't know that it had that alias.

Comment: You can even abbreviate `Name` to `N` and `Label` to `L` and `Expression` to `E` if you want (although I recommend spelling them out in scripts).

Comment: @HAL9256 finally it works (bug caused by some other filters interfering), I don't know to whom to attribute right answer though.

Answer (score 1):

To add to @Bill_Stewart's Answer.

```
$Dir = get-childitem C:\temp -recurse
$List = $Dir | where {$_.extension -eq ".txt"}
$List | format-table name, @{Label="Directory"; Expression={$_.Directory -replace "C:\\temp", ""}}
```

Comment: I still get this error: A null key is not allowed in a hash literal.

Comment: When you run just `$List | format-table name, Directory` are there any "bad" Directory entries?

Comment: I had some other filters, I recreate from scratch adding filters aftewards now it works :)

Comment: I don't know to whom attribute right answer so I checked first one but you've been also helpfull so thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but I came across this as I had a similar issue.  I didn't see the final solution in here, so I fiddled with it and this is what I got to work.  Had to replace double quotes with single quotes in the hash.

```
$Dir = get-childitem c:\temp -recurse
$List = $Dir | where {$_.extension -eq ".txt"}
$List | format-table name, @{Label='Directory'Expression={$_.Directory -replace 'C:\\temp', ''}}
```